# Cannot access parameter from Codeigniter URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, url-parameters

How to get the 3rd parameter from the Codeigniter url like http://domain.org/project/controller/view#tab-3/2. I need to access the 3rd parameter value ie, here ,`2` from the URL.

I tried with `$this->uri->segment(3);` and it is not returning any value. `$this->uri->segment(2);` returns the value `view` instead of `view#tab-3`.

What I am trying to do is pagination in CI. In my page I am using tabs. On clicking tab3 it will call an ajax function as shown below:

```
function receivedtickets(userid,baseurl)
{
    var pagenum=$('#pagenum').val();

    if(pagenum!="" && pagenum!=undefined)
    { 
        data='userid='+userid+'&pagenum='+pagenum;
    }
    else
    {
        data='userid='+userid;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:baseurl+'video/receivedtickets/'+pagenum,
        datatype:'json',
        data:data,
        success:function(response)
        { 
            $('#tab-3').html(response.results);
            $('#recpagination').html(response.pagination);
        }
    });
}
```

`pagenum` is a hidden field in my view page containing the tabs.

```
if($this->uri->segment(3))
        {
            $data['page_num']=$this->uri->segment(3);
        }
        else 
        {
            $data['page_num']=0;
        }
<input type="hidden" id="pagenum" value="<?php echo $data['page_num'];?>">
```

Controller code for pagination :

```
function receivedtickets()
    {
        if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) 
        {       // not logged in
            redirect(base_url().'auth/login');
        }
        $this->load->library('pagination');         // library for pagination

        $userid=$_POST['userid'];
        $per_pg=1;

        if($this->uri->segment(3))
        { 
            $page_num= $this->uri->segment(3);
            $offset=($page_num - 1) * $per_pg;   
        }
        else 
        {
            $offset=0;
        }

        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'video/tickets#tab-3'; 
        $config['total_rows'] = 50; 
        $config['div'] = '#pagination'; // div for displaying ajax
        $config['per_page'] = $per_pg; 
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config['page_query_string'] = FALSE;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
        $pagination=$this->pagination->create_links();

        $string="";
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT 
  s.send_on,
  s.sendby_id,
  t.ticket_key,
  t.video_id,
  a.first_name,
  a.last_name,
  v.title,
  v.videothumbnail ,
  s.sendto_id
FROM
  sendticket AS s 
  LEFT JOIN ticket AS t 
    ON s.ticketid = t.id 
  LEFT JOIN auth_user_profiles AS a 
    ON a.user_id = s.sendby_id 
  LEFT JOIN video AS v 
    ON t.video_id = v.videoid 
    WHERE (s.sendto_id = $userid or s.sendto_id ='gfhgfh@kgjgj.in')
ORDER BY s.send_on DESC limit $offset,$per_pg");

        $string.='<div class="tableoutertb">
                <table class="myticketsdivv">
                    <tr class="mytickets_row">
                        <td class="mytickets_colmn ">'.lang('video').'</td>
                        <td class="mytickets_colmn ">'.lang('title').'</td>
                    </tr>';

                    if($query->num_rows > 0)
                    {
                        foreach($query->result() as $row)
                        {
                          $string.='<tr class="mytickets_row">
                            <td class="mytickets_colmn">
                                <span class="mob_title">'.lang('video').'</span>
                                <a target="_blank" href="'.base_url().'video/playvideo/'.$row->video_id.'">';
                                    $string.='<img src="'.base_url().'images/No_image.png" style="max-width: 140px;" alt="Teshot featured video preview">';
                                $string.='</a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="mytickets_colmn">
                                <span class="mob_title">'.lang('title').'</span>
                                <a target="_blank" style="color: #3b5998;" href="'.base_url().'video/playvideo/'.$row->video_id.'">'.$row->title.'</a>
                            </td>
                            </tr>';
                        }
                        $string.='<tr class="mytickets_row"><td class="mytickets_colmn" colspan="5"><div class="pagination" style="position: initial;margin-top:0px;float:right;" id="recpagination"></div></td></tr>';
                    }
                $string.='</table>
                </div>';
                header('Content-type: application/json');
                $ret = array();
                $ret['results']=$string;
                $ret['pagination']= $pagination;
                echo json_encode($ret);
        exit;
    }
```

Can anyone help me to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The value after the hash (#) is never sent to the server - it is resoved in the browser, so php (codeignitor) will never know about it.

However is seems you are only accessing it to then imbed it into the page, for js to access.

Instead you can just grab the value from the url directly with js:

```
function receivedtickets(userid,baseurl)
{
    var hash = location.hash;
    var pagenum = hash.substr(hash.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

    if(pagenum!="" && pagenum!=undefined)
    {
        data='userid='+userid+'&pagenum='+pagenum;
    }
    else
    {
        data='userid='+userid;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:baseurl+'video/receivedtickets/'+pagenum,
        datatype:'json',
        data:data,
        success:function(response)
        {
            $('#tab-3').html(response.results);
            $('#recpagination').html(response.pagination);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @user574632..Thanks for your help. Now the problem is with pagination url. I need the url to be like http://domain.org/project/video/tickets/pagenumber/#tab-3